# liquibase initialization with r2dbc config

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, r2dbc

Trying to run spring boot with r2dbc and init database.
My build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    runtimeOnly 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-h2'
    runtimeOnly 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

Spring properties:

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test
spring.r2dbc.username=postgres
spring.r2dbc.password=123
spring.r2dbc.pool.enabled=true
spring.r2dbc.pool.initial-size=10
spring.data.r2dbc.repositories.enabled=true

spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test
spring.liquibase.user=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
logging.level.liquibase = INFO
```

And after starting it falls with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SimpleDriverDataSource
```

What do I do incorrectly?

Comment: upd. if I add org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency, it starts falling with NoBeanAvailable exception: can't instantiate Repository.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a dependency on `org.springframework:spring-jdbc`. From the [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-r2dbc):

> Alternatively, you can configure either Flyway or Liquibase to configure a DataSource for you for the duration of the migration. Both these libraries offer properties to set the url, username and password of the database to migrate.
>
> When choosing this option, `org.springframework:spring-jdbc` is still a required dependency.