# How do I make a DataR2dbcTest that uses liquibase for initialization

Tags: unit-testing, liquibase, testcontainers, r2dbc

[liquibase initialization with r2dbc config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738681/liquibase-initialization-with-r2dbc-config) shows how to set up R2DBC with Liquibase.  I want to create a test using test containers.

```kotlin
@DataR2dbcTest(properties = [
  "spring.datasource.url: jdbc:tc:mysql://mysql/gateway?TC_IMAGE_TAG=8",
"spring.r2dbc.url: r2dbc:tc:mysql://mysql/gateway?TC_IMAGE_TAG=8"])
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [
  Application::class,
  LiquibaseAutoConfiguration::class // this didn't work either
])
class ApplicationR2dbcTests {

  @Autowired lateinit var applicationContext: ApplicationContext
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: I used [r2dbc migrate](https://github.com/nkonev/r2dbc-migrate) in my project, worked well for the past two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the knowledge from the following answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979769/242042
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74863802/242042

```kotlin
@Testcontainers
@DataR2dbcTest()
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes =
        [
            Application::class,
            LiquibaseAutoConfiguration::class])
class ApplicationR2dbcTests {
  @Autowired lateinit var connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory

  companion object {
    @Container private var mySqlContainer = MySQLContainer("mysql:8")

    @JvmStatic
    @DynamicPropertySource
    fun registerDynamicProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
      registry.add("spring.liquibase.url") {
        "jdbc:mysql://${mySqlContainer.host}:${mySqlContainer.firstMappedPort}/${mySqlContainer.databaseName}"
      }
      registry.add("spring.liquibase.user") {
          mySqlContainer.username
      }
      registry.add("spring.liquibase.password") { mySqlContainer.password }

      registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url") {
        "r2dbc:mysql://${mySqlContainer.host}:${mySqlContainer.firstMappedPort}/${mySqlContainer.databaseName}"
      }
      registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username") { mySqlContainer.username }
      registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password") { mySqlContainer.password }
    }
  }

  @Test
  fun liquibaseChangesMade() {
      StepVerifier.create(DatabaseClient
         .create(connectionFactory)
         .sql("select count(*) from DATABASECHANGELOG")
          .map { it -> it.get(0) as Long }
          .all()
      )
          .expectNextMatches { it > 0 }
          .verifyComplete()
  }
}
```